# Azure YAML Pipeline not publishing to private Artifact Feed

Tags: azure, yaml, nuget, devops, publish

I have an extremely simple project and pipeline:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Create nuget package'
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
      packDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/packages/nuget'
      nobuild: true

  - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
    displayName: 'Authenticate with NuGet Feed'

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Push package to feed'
    inputs:
      command: push
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      publishVstsFeed: '<ProjectName>/TestFeedTwo'
```

I have created the feed to be scoped to my org, and I have disabled *Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines*, and I have ensured that all the Build Service and Project Build Services have access to the feed, and I can publish to the feed connection from the CLI, but for some reason I can't escape this error:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<ProjectName>/_packaging/TestFeedTwo/nuget/v3/index.json.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found - The feed with ID 'TestFeedTwo' doesn't exist. (DevOps Activity ID: 1F96FF8BD417)).)
##[error]Packages failed to publish
```

The package is getting created as expected, but I just can't seem to wire up this feed. I've done a fair bit of Googling, but I am getting desperate. Anyone else have any other suggestions?

I have created the feed to be scoped to my org
I have disabled *Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines*
I have ensured that all the Build Service and Project Build Services have access to the feed
I can publish to the feed from the CLI